# Кроссбраузерные, кроссистемные шрифты без зачечек

Tags: css

Необходимо подключить на сайт встроенные шрифты с помощью свойства `font-family`.

**Вопрос**: какие шрифты и в каком порядке нужно перечислить в `font-family`, чтобы в первую очередь шли самые универсальные (которые есть в большинстве систем)?

Задача именно в универсальности решения, чтобы такой вариант шрифтов можно было подключать по-умолчанию в каждом проекте, в которых не требуется использование внешних шрифтов.

Comment: Для семейства с засечками (serif) практически на всех платформах имеется Times, без засечек (sans-serif) - Arial.

Comment: парсер читает слева на право и сверху вниз

Comment: Вот что удалось [нарыть](https://habr.com/ru/post/68189/) при поиске, но это, конечно, только список и далеко не всех платформ, к тому же нет решения как автоматизированно считать шрифты, доступные в той или иной ОС, да ещё и разделив их на с засечками или без.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif`

Sans-serif - это не конкретный шрифт, а общая классификация шрифтов без засечек. Во всех нормальных системах присутствует минимум по одному шрифту из семейств Serif (с засечками), Sans-serif (без засечек) и Monospace (моноширинные).

И если вам надо, чтобы в первую очередь шли самые универсальные, то я вас разочарую - их нет. Вы можете подобрать максимально похожие - в моем примере для винды будет задействован Ариал, в макоси - Гельветика (второй в списке, т.к. Ариала там нет), если надо, добавьте еще для линукса и андроида, а для непредусмотренных случаев в самом конце воткните Sans-serif, чтобы система задействовала именно шрифт без засечек, хоть какой-то, ибо без этого по умолчанию будет системный serif.

Comment: Спасибо, вполне исчерпывающий ответ. Примерно такой ответ я и хотел получить :) `Arial` и `sans-serif` я всегда подключаю, делема была в том какие ещё шрифты добавить для большей полноты картины )